# using chart control in asp.net toolbox

Tags: asp.net, charts

I need to create charts for my web application using database data. I have a table callled *students* with another table *marks*. Using these two I want to plot marks obtained by students on a linear chart. I do not have an experience with ASP.NET chart controls. Is there a simple example to start with?

 I want to draw a 2-D line chart for marks of one class students. Next I'm going to calculate means for each class and create a bar chart comparing several classes. 

Furthermore, I want to see if these charts can be dynamically created and subsequently assigned values. For example, as the user chooses the number of classes to sketch plots for, they should dynamically be drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-ASPNet-Chart-Control-from-Database-using-C-and-VBNet-Example.aspx Hope it will help you to get some understanding.

Comment: I tried to run the example you referred me to in Visual Studio 2013. But I get the following error: 
**HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.**

Answer (score 0):

Check the httpHandlers configuration in IIS. Try following:

1. Open Server Manager
2. Select Roles>Web Server (IIS)>IIS Manager>Select the Server>Applocation Pools
3. Select the appPool that your asp.net app is running under>Click on 'Advanced Settings' from the right hand pane.
4. Under Advanced Settings>General>Managed Pipeline Mode, select "Classic"
5. Recycle app pool and test your app.

Comment: where is server manager in win 8.1? I can't find it. Also it can't be provoked from Run by intemgr

Comment: Check this budddy.http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9430/how-to-open-iis-manager-in-windows-8.aspx]